# After leaving .get array loses data

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv

I know there is something I am missing about Ajax but I need help to understand. In the following code myArray has its content at label "A" but is empty at label "B". The purpose of the code is to read multiple csv files, store some values from each of the files and use myArray later in the script. I know there must be something with vars in the Ajax request (.get). Thanks

```
var myArray = [];
var lines = [];

$.each(fileNames, function(lineNo, file) 
{
    $.get(file, function(data) 
    {
        lines = $.csv.toObjects(data);
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
        {
            ... code ...
            myArray.push(someValue);
        });
        --- A ---
    });
    --- B ---
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is asynchronous.

Any code placed at `B` will run while the `get` is happening.

Place any code you want to act on MyArray inside the function supplied to `get`, or place another call inside the get function to act on your data.

```
$.get(file, function(data) 
{
    lines = $.csv.toObjects(data);
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
    {
        ... code ...
        myArray.push(someValue);
    });

    // myArray is ready here. Place any code that acts on it here...
});

// myArray may not be ready here, since the `get` hasn't finished yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the get callback gets executed asynchronously when the get request return, but the code below the get call gets executed right away, before the callback.

You could execute synchronously replacing get with ajax async=false. This will be a bit slower as each call would not begin till the previous one ended.

```
var myArray = [];
var lines = [];

$.each(fileNames, function(lineNo, file) 
{
    $.ajax({
            url: file,
            success: function(data) {
                    lines = $.csv.toObjects(data);
                    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
                            {
                                ... code ...
                                myArray.push(someValue);
                            });
                    },
            async:false
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not a good enough reason to turn off asynchronous functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the async:false approach you could use this:

```
var myArray = [];
var lines = [];
var count = 0;

$.each(fileNames, function(lineNo, file) 
{
    $.get(file, function(data) 
    {
        lines = $.csv.toObjects(data);
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
        {
            ... code ...
            myArray.push(someValue);
        });
    }).done(function(){
        count++;
        if(count > fileNames.lenght){
            // Code to use array goes here
        }
    });
});
```